# Why is Google Cloud SQL MySQL driver not returning all field values that have the same name?

Tags: mysql, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I'm writing a firebase function that executes query `SELECT A.*, B.* FROM A INNER JOIN B ON ... WHERE ...` against a MySQL database hosted on Google Cloud SQL. The two tables A and B have some columns with identical names. In particular, both have an "id" column. However, the result only contains one `id` column and it always has the value of `B.id`.

I can work around this by not using `A.*, B.*` and instead selecting specific column names, but there are a lot of columns, which make the `*` so much more convenient. Is there a way to have the database driver return all columns suitably marked with the tablename alias, or is rewriting the query without `A.*, B.*` the only way?

As a partial fix I can `SELECT A.id AS A_id, B.id AS B_id, A.*, B.*` which does get those two values separately. But then (a) there is still a spurious `id` column in the result set, which is an ugly copy of `B.id`, and (b) there are other pairs of identically named columns between the tables. So I'm hoping for a generic solution, like some option to have the driver label the output fields with the tablename aliases.

Those columns are very much part of the result set so it's amazing to me that this driver is effectively dropping some columns just because the name is the same.

Thank you.

EDIT: Here is a simple example. First the tables:

```
mysql> describe A;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> describe B;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> select * from A;
+----+------+
| id | code |
+----+------+
|  1 | abc  |
|  2 | def  |
|  3 | ghi  |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> select * from B;
+----+------+
| id | code |
+----+------+
|  4 | xyz  |
|  5 | abc  |
|  6 | def  |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> select A.*, B.* from A INNER JOIN B on A.code = B.code;
+----+------+----+------+
| id | code | id | code |
+----+------+----+------+
|  1 | abc  |  5 | abc  |
|  2 | def  |  6 | def  |
+----+------+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Then the firebase call to retrieve this query, with error handling and other stuff removed.

```
export const sql = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return corsFn(req, res, async () => {      
    const query = 'select A.*, B.* from A INNER JOIN B on A.code = B.code';
    
    const pool: mysql.Pool = mysql.createPool({
      // cloud sql proxy
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 3306,
      user: functions.config().cloud_sql.user,
      password: functions.config().cloud_sql.password,
      database: functions.config().cloud_sql.database,
      connectionLimit: 20,
    });
    pool.query(query, [], (err: mysql.MysqlError | null, results: any) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(404).send(err);
      } else {
        res.status(200).send(results);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And finally here is the JSON result:

```
[
 {"id":5,"code":"abc"},
 {"id":6,"code":"def"}
]
```

There is only one "id" in the result and that is from the second table. So I'm simply asking if there's a way to use "*" in the select and have it return all columns, with the `A.id` and `B.id` marked differently somehow.

Comment: What is it you are logically trying to achieve?  Are you joining on the id column found in both A and B tables?

Comment: @Kolban Nothing special at all. The A.id and B.id are just autoincrement primary keys. The join is on some other column. However, I want A.id and B.id to be present in the result set, not just B.id. If you run the join in a MySQL client you get both columns, so the question is, why does the GCP MySQL driver return only the B.id

Comment: Can you share the full query you are running with the table structures of the two different tables and the result you are getting? Also, if possible add the data of two tables redacting any sensitive information.

Comment: @Prabir The tables in question are quite large. But the join query is very simple, it is just "SELECT A.*, B.* FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.X = B.X", where X is some other column (neither A.id or B.id). The result set , when I log it in the firebase function has only one "id" column.  I don't think it has anything at all to do with the specific tables.

Comment: @Prabir I edited the question and shared the query, table structures and results. Thanks.

Comment: It seems you are making some mistake in the function code. I tried to implement it using Firebase Functions and I could get the data as expected. Can you provide the full function code and state which language you are using?

Comment: @Prabir I added the full function code above. It's a firebase function, written in Typescript. When you say you "get the data as expected", can you post the results you get from the HTTP function call? How are those two different ID fields identified in your result object? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the [results](https://i.imgur.com/cBHcVrN.png). The result has the data from both the tables but they are not specified with the table alias. In your case you said that you are getting the id field from one table and the other is missing.

Comment: @Prabir Unfortunately without seeing your tables or query it's hard to know what your result is showing. As you can see in my result, the http query has only 2 columns, whereas selecting ```A.*```, ```B.*``` has 4 columns as we see in the MySQL result. So the question is how to get those other columns and still use ```*``` if possible. Anyway, I have just rewritten the query without ```*``` and moved on, so  thank you for trying.